# How to add a span class in the following php?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following code to display posts in Wordpress

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&show_post_count=1'); ?>
```

How can I add a span class around the count so I can style it?

The above code produces this:

October (9)
November (22)
December (3)

I need to assign a span class to the count, and not entire output.

Comment: Could you provide the html that generates?

Comment: What is the html behind that?

Comment: updated the post to display the html

Comment: Valid question and a perfect example of displaying the shortcomings of Wordpress' inner workings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest option is with a little bit of CCS magic.  At the moment, I am assuming your template code (for the archive block) is along the lines of:

```
<ul>
  <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&show_post_count=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

**Firstly**, add a class to your list:

```
<ul class="archiveList">
  <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&show_post_count=1'); ?>
</ul>
```

**Secondly**, add some lines to your CSS to style the relevant bits

```
.achiveList li {color: red;} /* This is the style for the post count */
.achiveList li a {color: blue;} /* This is the style for the link */
```

The Hard option is to set the "echo" parameter on wp_get_achives to 0/false. <strike>That way the method will return an array of data and leave it up to your to loop over it and print it out.</strike> **Edit** My mistake, it returns it just as a string, which means this is going to be quite tricky. Depends on how much styling you need to apply.

Comment: i specifically need the span class on the number output in the php string. Month (number)

Comment: The above will style the parentheses as well as the number within.  If you just want to style the number, then you are going to have to either: follow the "Hard" option and parse the return string from wp_get_archives using some reg-ex hacks, or write your own template function to generate this how you want it.

Comment: ah yes i am retarded. well, mentally challenged. this worked perfectly!